Exercise 2.19 from Cochran's - Sampling techniques
I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Cochran's "Sampling Techniques ":

This exercise is another example of estimators geared to particular features of populations.
After the decision to take a simple random sample had been made, it was realized that $ y_1 $would be unusually low and $ y_N $ would be unusually high.
For this situation, Särndal (1972) examined the following unbiased estimator of $ \bar{Y} $:
$$
\hat{Y}_S = 
\begin{cases}
    \bar{y} + c & \text{if the sample contains } y_1 \text{ but not } y_N, \\
    \bar{y} - c & \text{if the sample contains } y_N \text{ but not } y_1, \\
    \bar{y} & \text{for all other samples}.
\end{cases}
$$
where $ c $ is a constant. Prove Särndal's result that $\hat{Y}_S $ is unbiased with
$$
V(\hat{Y}_S) = (1 - f) \left[ \frac{S^2}{n} - \frac{2c}{N-1}(y_N - y_1 - nc) \right]
$$
so that $ V(\hat{Y}_S) < V(\bar{y})$  if  $0 < c < \frac{(y_N - y_1)}{n} $

I don't understand how to raise the variance in this case, the only thing that occurs is
\begin{align*}
P(\hat{Y}_S = \overline{y} + c) & = \frac{ \binom{1}{1} \binom{1}{0} \binom{N-2}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}} = \frac{\binom{N-2}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}} \\
P(\hat{Y}_S = \overline{y} - c) & = \frac{ \binom{1}{0} \binom{1}{1} \binom{N-2}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}} = \frac{\binom{N-2}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}} \\
P(\hat{Y}_S = \overline{y} ) & = 1 - P(\hat{Y}_S = \overline{y} + c) - P(\hat{Y}_S = \overline{y} - c)
\end{align*}
Nor can I think of how to calculate the covariance or variance in the case of using $\overline{Y}_S = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} Z_i y_i $. Appreciate any kind of help or suggestion. Greetings
